# Moving between buttons with keyboard events

Tags: qt, qt4, keyboard

I know I need an event filter for Qt 4 to handle keyboard events.  But I previously had something similar working without a need to manually configure this.  I've read the documentation for it, but I was unable to get an event eater setup for the application.  I don't need events managed at the button level.

Here is example code that illustrates two buttons that will not focus or activate except by mouse click.  I would like one to have focus by default on one button, which I can do with `button.setFocus()`.  I would also like to be able to navigate buttons which are active by using tab, or up/down keys then activate with enter/space.  The problem is I'm confused on how to implement it.  Do I need to inherit some Q* class and implement an event filter class, then install on objects?  Or is there a more simple way?

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QWidget>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QWidget window;
    window.resize(200, 200);

    QPushButton quit("Quit", &window);
    quit.setGeometry(10, 40, 180, 40);
    QObject::connect(&quit, SIGNAL(clicked()), &app, SLOT(quit()));

    QPushButton nothing("Do Nothing", &window);
    nothing.setGeometry(10, 80, 180, 40);

    quit.setFocus();
    window.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Cant you just define a keyPressEvent on your main window?

Comment: @jdi I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: I realize you already solved your problem with the osx setting, but you can read this to understand events more in depth:  http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq11-events.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do anything to be able to navigate between buttons using tab or cursor keys, [this is the default behavior](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/focus.html).

Comment: Yeah, uhm.... the example code I posted seems the contradict this.  Enter, space, tab, etc do nothing, even if I manually setFocus on a button first.  Only clicking works.

Comment: Sorry, the example code I posted already implements setFocus, which makes the space bar "click" the quit button, but otherwise, no keyboard events do anything.

Comment: I compiled and ran your code and I was able to navigate between the two buttons with the tab key and the cursor keys. I can activate a button with the space bar. If you add `quit.setDefault(true)` you can activate that button with the enter key. This is with Windows 7 / MinGW / Qt 4.8.

Comment: interesting.  I'm using Mac OS X 10.7.3 and none of that works.

Comment: I don't have a Mac but a quick search turned this up. Does it apply? http://www.macyourself.com/2009/08/22/navigate-mac-os-x-dialog-boxes-using-only-your-keyboard/

Answer (score 0):

See [QWiget::focusPolicy](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#focusPolicy-prop) to prevent widgets from getting focus.

Comment: I've tried `window.setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);` already, and it doesn't change the behavior.